# Can anyone help me understand how this for loop is running?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am pretty familiar with the enumerate and 'range(len(iterable)' way of looping through a for loop. However, for whatever reason I can't seem to understand why the for loop is producing the following output.

```
lst = [-2, 0, 4, 5, 1, 2]

for num, b in enumerate(lst):
    print(lst[b])
```

Output :

```
1
-2
1
2
0
4
```

- I understand if I were to print(lst[num]) it would print the items of the list.
- If I were to print(i) I would also print the items of the list.
- If I print(num) I would print the indices.

I just can't figure out where the output is getting the numbers from.

Comment: use backtick ` not ' to create code blocks

Comment: `num` is the index, `b` is the element (which makes those pretty bad names). You don't have an `i`. But note that the elements are integers, they're _also valid indices_.

Comment: The use of enumerate here is irrelevant. The loop does not use the index variable `num`. It might as well be `for b in lst:`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I understand python automatically creates indices for all elements, but I want to know where python is getting the values for the output

Comment: _From the list_ that you're indexing into. Note that all the values you print out are also in `lst`, this is **not** a coincidence.

Comment: I can't understand how there is a question here. You have code that says `print(lst[b])`; and you *know what `lst` is, and what `b` is*, and how the `[]` work; but you still don't understand what is being printed? Alternately: you understand how `lst[num]` works, but you don't understand how `lst[b]` works, *even though* you can see that `num` and `b` are both integers?

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [-2, 0, 4, 5, 1, 2]

for index, value in enumerate(lst):
    print(value)
    # Prints each value
  
for index, value in enumerate(lst):
    print(index)
    # Prints each index

for index, value in enumerate(lst):
    print(lst[index])
    # Prints each value (but not really benefiting from enumerate)

for index, value in enumerate(lst):
    print(lst[value])
    # Meaningless 
    # Only works since value itself is an int 
    # Prints some element in lst whose index equals to value
```

Answer (score 1):

For the enumerate function, `b` refers to the elements. But since the elements are also valid indices for the loop, they return a value.
SO:

```
lst = [-2, 0, 4, 5, 1, 2]

for num, b in enumerate(lst):
    print(lst[b])
```

In this Every iteration is:

```
1) b = -2 => print(lst[b]) => lst[-2] => 1
2) b = 0 => print(lst[b]) => lst[0] => -2
3) b = 4 => print(lst[b]) => lst[4] => 1
4) b = 5 => print(lst[b]) => lst[5] => 2
5) b = 1 => print(lst[b]) => lst[1] => 0
6) b = 2 => print(lst[b]) => lst[2] => 4
```

Hence this is valid

Comment: Well, what's the reason to use `enumerate()` there?

Comment: No specific reason, it would work even without enumerate. It might just be given as it is often thought to be a better practice to use enumerate in functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're confused about why a piece of code is doing what it doing, it's frequently helpful to have it print out exactly what it's doing.  In this case, printing out the values of `b`:

```
>>> lst = [-2, 0, 4, 5, 1, 2]
>>> for b in lst:
...     print(f"lst[{b}] = {lst[b]}")
...
lst[-2] = 1
lst[0] = -2
lst[4] = 1
lst[5] = 2
lst[1] = 0
lst[2] = 4
```

As you can see, the `b` values go through the `lst` elements in order, and the `lst[b]` values that get printed on the right (which are the only values you printed originally) do indeed correspond to what you get by indexing `lst`.

Note that lists are zero-indexed, so `lst[0]` is the first element (-2), and a negative index counts that many spaces from the end, so `lst[-2]` is the second element from the end (1, the same as `lst[4]`).